# yii2 send API request command

Tags: yii2

Need to execute the following API call:

```
GET /v1/users HTTP/1.1
Host: https://api.someserver.com
Authorization: Bearer MyT0KenGoesH3r3
```

so far for Yii2 there is lots of documentation about creating your own API, but not how to send a query. Do I need an extension to do this, or am I looking at something like https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle?

Comment: see [https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-httpclient](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-httpclient)

Comment: please submit this as an answer and I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a HTTP Client Extension for Yii 2. Take a look at https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-httpclient